# Start application when Content provider is changed

Tags: android, settings, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I want my application to start when someone modifies a content provider. A setting to be specific. The settings framework calls "notify" when a value is set.

If my app was started I would use registerContentObserver() I guess, but is is not started.

Can define some intent-filter in my manifest that wakes up my application. A back up plan would be to have a service running all the time that has registered a listener, but that seems like a wast or resources.

Thanks, Ola

Answer (score -1):

This isn't directly supported by the Android device because starting an app every time a ContentProvider's data changes is a path to really killing your battery.  To do the query, you'd need to do it in a service, which as you said is understandably undesirable.

Secondly, starting an intent is a *user* action.  Android really doesn't support allowing an application to start all on its own without user request...  Doing so would be impolite!  What if your user was doing something important and then your app pops up on top?  Remember the user is in control, not you.  Instead of starting an application, consider placing a [Status Bar Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) so the user can deal with it when it's convenient for them.